# Process in python socketserver

Tags: python, sockets

If we run code from [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/socketserver.html#asynchronous-mixins), the output will be:

```
Server loop running in thread: Thread-1
Received: Thread-2: Hello World 1
Received: Thread-3: Hello World 2
Received: Thread-4: Hello World 3
```

I want to use **multiprocessing**, so I change the code like that:

```
import socket
import socketserver
import multiprocessing

class TCPRequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        data = str(self.request.recv(1024), 'ascii')
        cur_proceess = multiprocessing.current_process()
        response = bytes("{}: {}".format(cur_proceess.name, data), 'ascii')
        self.request.sendall(response)

class TCPServer(socketserver.ForkingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    pass

def client(ip, port, message):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((ip, port))
    try:
        sock.sendall(bytes(message, 'ascii'))
        response = str(sock.recv(1024), 'ascii')
        print("Received: {}".format(response))
    finally:
        sock.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Port 0 means to select an arbitrary unused port
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 0

    server = TCPServer((HOST, PORT), TCPRequestHandler)
    ip, port = server.server_address

    server_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=server.serve_forever)
    server_process.daemon = True
    server_process.start()
    print("Server loop running in process:", server_process.name)

    client(ip, port, "Hello World 1")
    client(ip, port, "Hello World 2")
    client(ip, port, "Hello World 3")

    server.shutdown()
```

In output:

```
Server loop running in process: Process-1
Received: Process-1: Hello World 1
Received: Process-1: Hello World 2
Received: Process-1: Hello World 3
```

Why **Process-1**? How to start new process for each new connection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

think the processes are baing started, they're just not named as nicely as threads.

try to output os.getpid() instead of the current_process().name and you will see different pid with each response

Answer (score 0):

I find solution: use **Process.pid** instead of **Process.name**